# Start video at a specific time using Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video

Is it possible to start a video using VideoPlayer at a specific time ?
Say for example, 30 seconds after the beginning ?

I can't figure out how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that by setting [`time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-time.html).

Note though from [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-get-unity-videoplayer-to-set-time-seek.522492/) it isn't that easy.

The API confuses me a lot as well tbh but I think something like this should work

You could do that in a routine like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

public void SetClipWithTime(VideoClip clip, float time) 
{
    StartCoroutine (SetTimeRoutine(clip, time));
}

IEnumerator SetTimeRoutine (VideoClip clip, float time)
{
    if(videoPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        videoPlayer.Stop();
    }

    videoPlayer.clip = clip;

    videoPlayer.Prepare();
    yield return new WaitUntil (() => videoPlayer.isPrepared);  
    yield return new WaitUntil (() => videoPlayer.canSetTime);

    videoPlayer.Play();
    videoPlayer.time = time;
}
```

Those two `yield return new ...` might be redundant. You will have to test it (not on a PC right now).

Note also from [`canSetTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-canSetTime.html) that not all video formats and especially streaming via URL support this at all!